# Nest html tags inside html

Tags: html

I am building a platform where people can send emails - to display a preview of the emails, I use a div below the form where they can type the message.

So the general structure looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
         <form>
              <!-- Form to enter email here -->
         </form>
         <div>
              <!-- Email preview here -->
              <html>
                   <!-- Email content, updated everytime user types something --->
              </html>
         </div>
    </bod>
</html>
```

However, simply using the html tags inside the html document itself seems to confuse every browser - also, it doesn't seem very clean.

Since the email that is sent will be a whole html document of its own, it would be the easiest to just put all that inside the div.

How can I do that in a valid, clean way?

Comment: Probably because it's invalid HTML. If you must use `html` tags, use an `iframe`.

Comment: I thought about the iframe solution, but it looks really weird - apparently it is expecting some source. How can I make it display what's inside without loading it from another source?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with php

Comment: Why not just not put the <html> tags and just add them in before sending the email?

Comment: Well, the email will be sent with php, of course - but I will remove the tag.

Comment: Why do you need the extra HTML tags? Why don't you just use the DIV to display the content and then add the HTML tags when sending the email if they're necessary

Comment: Yep, I think that's the approach I will take

Comment: Thanks for your many answers - as some commenters have put, it is the best way to just put everything inside a div and then put the html around it in the script that sends the email.

Answer (score 6):

Use an iframe. You can write dynamic content to them - you don't always have to load physical pages into them with an `src` attribute.

HTML:

```
<iframe name='preview'></iframe>
```

JS (inside DOM-ready callback)

```
var doc = document.preview.open("text/html","replace");
doc.write('<html><body><p>this is some content</p></body></html>');
doc.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get this around using the approach you have used. Getting emails rendered in mail clients is a chalenge, You may want to use an iframe instead. However you have to make sure that the contents of an email copy have to be fully in a table layout format.

Comment: The iframe seems to expect a source, but I would like to put the content directly inside the frame tags. This doesn't seem to work...